# Paste Workbook.Queries into arrays without pasting to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a bit of a problem with some query connections that I want to deal with inside an array because they can hold more rows than Excel can handle.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RefrescaConsultas()
    EliminaConsultas
    CreaConsultas
End Sub
Private Sub EliminaConsultas()

    Dim Consulta As Object
    For Each Consulta In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        Consulta.Delete
    Next Consulta

End Sub
Private Sub CreaConsultas()
    
    Dim Mes As String: Mes = HMacro.Range("B2")
    Dim Año As Long: Año = HMacro.Range("B1")
    Dim MesNum As Byte: MesNum = Month(DateValue("01/" & Mes & "/2020"))
    Dim RutaAccess As String: RutaAccess = Chr(34) & "\\ate2899cor01\reporting_administrativos\TELEFONICA\GP\Informe Evolucion Territorios\2020\Modelo Marzo´20\Inforrme Evolucion Ventas\Nuevo informe\BBDD\Actualiza Conversores.accdb" & Chr(34)
    
    'Brutas
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Brutas", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Brutas = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Brutas""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.Rem" & _
        "oveColumns(_Brutas,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_estado_fin"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"",  ""producto_alta_comercial"",  ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""faro"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", " & _
        """telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provincia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""producto_comision_actualizad" & _
        "o"", ""importe_comision"", ""COD_T9"", ""rf_tq"", ""operacion"", ""sub_producto_destino_alta_comercial"", ""num_lineas_movil_tipo_fusion"", ""num_lineas_movil_planta"", ""in_fusion"", ""anul_15"", ""anul_30"", ""anul_60"", ""co_resolucion_sia"", ""resolucion_sia"", ""causa_anulacion"", ""fuente_origen"", ""cliente_nuevo"", ""in_servicio_tv""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Dat" & _
        "e.Month([fx_solicitud]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""
    'TV
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "TV", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _TV = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""TV""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.RemoveColum" & _
        "ns(_TV,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_estado_fin"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""producto_alta_comercial"", ""sub_producto_destino_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provincia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cli" & _
        "ente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""no_sucursal"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""baja_prematura"", ""dias_baja"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""importe_comision"", ""COD_T9"", ""rf_tq"", ""nu_administra"", ""fuente" & _
        "_origen"", ""ds_fusion_origen"", ""ds_fusion_destino"", ""baja_prematura_8_mes_sig"", ""IN_PLANTA_8_MES_SIG"", ""CLIENTE_NUEVO""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_solicitud]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""

    'Fusion
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Fusion", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Fusion = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Fusion""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.Rem" & _
        "oveColumns(_Fusion,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_solicitud"", ""fx_devengo"", ""fx_instalacion"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""producto_alta_comercial"", ""sub_producto_destino_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provincia" & _
        "_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""matricula_origen"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""baja_prematura"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""COD_T9"", ""valor_origen"", ""valor_destino"", ""rf_tq"", " & _
        """dif_dias_baja"", ""in_servicio_tv_origen"", ""in_servicio_tv_destino"", ""num_lineas_movil_tipo_fusion"", ""num_lineas_movil_planta"", ""CUC"", ""fuente_origen"", ""fx_alta_desco""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_estado_fin]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""
    
    'Inserciones
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Inserciones", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Inserciones = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Inserciones""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" =" & _
        " Table.RemoveColumns(_Inserciones,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_estado_fin"", ""estado"", ""causa_estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provi" & _
        "ncia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""cod_comision_alta_comercial"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""importe_comision"", ""co_contrato"", ""co_plantari"", ""operado" & _
        "r_origen"", ""operador_destino"", ""ICC"", ""LIQUIDABLE"", ""TARJETA_VIRTUAL"", ""NUMERO_REPETICIONES"", ""FUENTE_ORIGEN""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_solicitud]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""

    'Prosegur
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Prosegur", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Prosegur = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Prosegur""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table" & _
        ".RemoveColumns(_Prosegur,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_estado_fin"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_solicitado"", ""indicador_negocio_solicitado"", ""producto_solicitado"", ""sub_producto_destino_solicitado"", ""subproducto_origen_solicitado"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""producto_alta_comercial"", ""sub_producto_destino_a" & _
        "lta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""CUC"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""localidad_cliente"", ""provincia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""matricula_origen"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta" & _
        """, ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""pais_vendedor"", ""FechaGrab"", ""FechaGrabInci"", ""in_fusion"", ""tipo"", ""nu_administra"", ""unidades"", ""id_senializacion"", ""cod_comision_solicitado"", ""producto_comision_solicitado"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""id_lead"", ""COD_T9"", ""rf_tq"", ""producto_comision_actualizado"", ""fuente_origen"", """ & _
        "co_unico"", ""fecha_compromiso_ini"", ""fecha_alta_sistema"", ""Campo61"", ""Campo62"", ""Campo63""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_solicitud]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""
    
    'Repos Móvil
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Repos", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Repos = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Repos""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.Remov" & _
        "eColumns(_Repos,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_solicitud"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_solicitado"", ""indicador_negocio_solicitado"", ""sub_producto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""sub_producto_destino_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_destino_alta_comercial"", " & _
        """soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""localidad_cliente"", ""provincia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""matricula_origen"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""pais_vendedor" & _
        """, ""in_fusion"", ""tipo"", ""operador_origen"", ""operador_destino"", ""in_terminal"", ""FechaGrab"", ""FechaGrabInci"", ""co_contrato_origen"", ""co_contrato_destino"", ""co_plantari_origen"", ""co_plantari_destino"", ""cod_comision_solicitado"", ""producto_comision_solicitado"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""ICC"", ""FUENTE_ORIGEN"", ""Arpu_Origen"", " & _
        """Arpu_Destino"", ""unidades""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_estado_fin]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""
    
    'Terminales
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Terminales", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Terminales = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Terminales""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = T" & _
        "able.RemoveColumns(_Terminales,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_solicitud"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""producto_alta_comercial"", ""sub_producto_destino_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provinci" & _
        "a_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", ""canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""importe_comision"", ""vendedor_entrega"", ""canal_venta_entrega"", ""agrupacion_canal_entrega"", """ & _
        "canal_entrega"", ""detalle_canal_entrega"", ""co_proveedor_entrega"", ""no_empresa_entrega"", ""co_centro_venta_entrega"", ""no_sucursal_entrega"", ""provincia_venta_entrega"", ""territorio_venta_entrega"", ""tipo"", ""gama_terminal"", ""in_financiado"", ""nu_imei"", ""cod_campania"", ""FUENTE_ORIGEN"", ""Campo56"", ""Campo57"", ""Campo58"", ""Campo59"", ""Campo60""" & _
        ", ""Campo61""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_estado_fin]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""

    'Móvil
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "Movil", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _Movil = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""Movil""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.Remov" & _
        "eColumns(_Movil,{""fx_proceso"", ""fx_solicitud"", ""fx_devengo"", ""estado"", ""operacion"", ""cod_indicador_negocio_alta_comercial"", ""subproducto_origen_alta_comercial"", ""co_modven"", ""soporte"", ""codigo_pedido"", ""tipo_doc"", ""id_fiscal"", ""CUC"", ""telefono"", ""segmento"", ""provincia_cliente"", ""ccaa_cliente"", ""territorio_cliente"", ""vendedor"", " & _
        """canal_venta"", ""co_proveedor"", ""no_empresa"", ""co_centro_venta"", ""provincia_venta"", ""ccaa_venta"", ""territorio_venta"", ""FechaGrab"", ""unidades"", ""baja_prematura"", ""dif_dias_baja"", ""producto_comision_alta_comercial"", ""importe_comision"", ""in_terminal"", ""co_contrato"", ""co_plantari"", ""operador_origen"", ""operador_destino"", ""ICC"", ""fuen" & _
        "te_origen""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each Date.Month([fx_estado_fin]) = " & MesNum & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"""
    
    'TMO
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add "TMO", "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Access.Database(File.Contents(" & RutaAccess & "), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _TMO = Origen{[Schema="""",Item=""TMO""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Columnas quitadas"" = Table.RemoveCol" & _
        "umns(_TMO,{""semana"", ""New_Territorio"", ""PAIS_TABLA"", ""MODO TABLA"", ""MODO TABLA TMO"", ""FX_LLAMADA"", ""NO_SEGMENTO"", ""NO_TERRITORIO"", ""NO_SUBTERRITORIO"", ""NO_PROVEEDOR"", ""NO_ORIGEN"", ""Terri_cliente"", ""Subterri_cliente"", ""ORIGEN"", ""NO_SEGMENTO_SKILL"", ""CO_GRABACION"", ""CLIENTE_NUEVO"", ""DS_SEGMENTO_ORGANIZATIVO"", ""B2C"", ""Idioma"", """ & _
        "CO_TIPO_EMISION"", ""IN_AGENDADA"", ""CA_RECIBIDAS"", ""CA_LLAMADAA_VALIDAA"", ""CA_Atendidas_Entrantes"", ""CA_Aten_20seg"", ""CA_Conv_M20Seg"", ""CA_TMO"", ""CA_TMO_S"", ""CA_TME"", ""CA_Tr_Imputables"", ""CA_Transferidas"", ""CA_Salientes"", ""CA_AGENDADAS"", ""CA_TMO_AGENDADAS""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Columnas quitadas"", each [Mes] =" & _
         MesNum & ")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas1"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Filas filtradas"", each [Año] = " & Año & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filas filtradas1"""

End Sub
```

The code is fairly simple, I've manually recorded Data->from data base->selected the data base->deleted some columns for each connection and filtered some data.

Now the workbook has all these connections that I need to work with, but pasting them into a sheet and then into an array might be a problem because some of them are more than 1M rows... Any Insight on how to achieve this?

Comment: The `Workbook.Queries` object is designed to return the query to a sheet, is probably the wrong approach here.  Consider switching to an [ADO approach](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w) which will return the Query results to a RecordSet object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Specifications and Limits for Excel Worksheets and Workbooks**
Total number of rows and columns in a worksheet :
1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns
so you may have to add a clause to limit the number of rows: select TOP 1000 in your SQL request

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Customer;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT TOP 10OO fx_proceso FROM [Prosegur]")
```